# CUDA is accumulating results from previous run

Tags: cuda

i am facing weird case that local arrays in the kernel are keeping their values from the previous run, and new values are accumulative results of all runs.
i delete the array which were defined dynamically. however the keep accumulating the results.
here is an example and code below:
the first run results were:

```
Before: 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 
After: 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 ,
```

then the next run results were:

```
Before: 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 
After: 2 , 4 , 6 , 8 , 10 , 12 , 14 , 16 , 18 ,
```

an so on, the previous run values are not cleared.  the question where is glitch? and how can i fix it.

my environment is :

OS: Linux SL7

GPU: Tesla K20m (SM_35)

CUDA version: 8.0

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void myKernel(int *data, int vectorSize)
{

    int const size = vectorSize;
    int *countArray = new int[size];
    /*Print array values before modifications*/
    printf("\nBefore: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d , ", countArray[i]);
    }

    /*Modifying array values*/
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; ++i)
    {
        countArray[i] += data[i];
    }
    printf("\nAfter: ");
    /*Print array values after modifications*/
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; ++i)
    {
         printf("%d , ", countArray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    delete[] countArray;
}
int main(void)
{
     const int size = 9;
     int array[size] ={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
     int *dev_array;
     cudaMalloc((void**) &dev_array, size * sizeof(int));
     cudaMemcpy(dev_array, array, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

     myKernel<<<1, 1>>>(dev_array, size);
     cudaFree(dev_array);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you use in-kernel `new` or `malloc`, you are allocating from a limited area. The runtime lets you know if an allocation failed by returning a NULL pointer. Your error in your "answer" (hint: edit your question instead) shows an invalid write to an address of 0 - a NULL pointer. So what may be happening in your "real" code that you haven't shown, is that you are exceeding the available space for your `new` allocations. You can adjust the limit, and may want to read the [docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations).

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to explicitly initialize `countArray` to zeros before using it. Uninitialized array could have any value in it. Just do

```
  for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; ++i)
  {
    countArray[i] = 0;
  }
```

before using `countArray`.

Comment: i tried this solution, but in my code (not this one) initialize the array when there is a lot of threads are running is causing memory leaks and leading for incorrect results. is there any other way to avoid this issue ? or what is causing this issue? is it locating the array on same locations on each run?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by memory leaks? There should not be any memory leak here. 
Yes. It seems the array is  in the same memory location. Since you didn't initialize it, the old value are somehow kept there and ended up accumulating.